# Capturing Elements as a Javascript Array Using XPath in CasperJS

Tags: javascript, xpath, casperjs, getelementsbytagname

I've been working with CasperJS for a web scraping project I'm doing, and have been having some trouble getting it to work perfectly.

The `getElementsAttribute` has been working pretty well as a way to capture the `href` and `title` information from the tables, but in some cases the tables aren't hyperlinked, but needs to be scraped anyway.  Here's the beginning portion of the code:

```
// Load utilities

var utils = require('utils');
var client = require('clientutils');
var fs = require('fs');
var x = require('casper').selectXPath;
var casper = require('casper').create({

pageSettings: {
    loadImages:  false,        
    loadPlugins: false 
},

clientScripts:  ['C:/casperjs/lib/jquery.min.js','C:/casperjs/lib/jquery.csv-0.71.min.js']

});

// Choose Main URL and Target Links

var mainURL = "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identification_badges_of_the_United_States_military";
var mainAttribute = '//*[@id="mw-content-text"]/ul/li/div/div/p/a';
var mainElement = '//*[@id="mw-content-text"]/ul/li/div/div/p';

casper.start();

casper.open(mainURL).then(function(){

// Choose Links from Main URL

mainLinks = this.getElementsAttribute(x(mainAttribute),'href');
mainTitle = this.getElementsAttribute(x(mainAttribute),'title');
mainFetch = document.getElementsByTagName(x(mainElement));

utils.dump(mainFetch);

});

casper.run();
```

The `getElementsAttribute` gives me the right information, but the `getElementsByTagName` only gives me an "undefined" or empty result even when I play around with the content inside.  (this.getElementsByTagName doesn't seem to work).

Basically I want to grab the text in instances where the hyperlink is missing, and push it into an array that's the same size/order of mainLinks and mainTitle using a single XPath selector.  Seems like there ought to be an easy way to do this but I haven't been able to figure it out.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `mainFetch = this.getElementsInfo(x(mainElement));` 
As you can see in the below snippet of output, it captures all children and the html section can be used to filter out children that do not begin with a '

```
{
    "attributes": {},
    "height": 54,
    "html": "<a href=\"/wiki/CPO_Command_Identification_Badge\" title=\"CPO Command Identification Badge\" class=\"mw-redirect\">Chief Petty Officer Command Identification Badges</a>",
    "nodeName": "p",
    "tag": "<p><a href=\"/wiki/CPO_Command_Identification_Badge\" title=\"CPO Command Identification Badge\" class=\"mw-redirect\">Chief Petty Officer Command Identification Badges</a></p>",
    "text": "Chief Petty Officer Command Identification Badges",
    "visible": true,
    "width": 147,
    "x": 185,
    "y": 9302
},
{
    "attributes": {},
    "height": 18,
    "html": "Law Enforcement Badges",
    "nodeName": "p",
    "tag": "<p>Law Enforcement Badges</p>",
    "text": "Law Enforcement Badges",
    "visible": true,
    "width": 147,
    "x": 185,
    "y": 9526
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I think this might work.  Will get back to you after I try it out!

Comment: It's been working a lot smoother now -- although what would you recommend for the best way to filter out the `html` data to get the `href` attribute?